# Why does greater than behave like this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I'm looking at Comparison operators in Javascript and came across these examples:

```
console.log(1 < 2 < 3);
```

This equals **true**, which feels like it makes sense as 1 is less than, 2 and 2 is less than 3...

```
console.log(3 > 2 > 1);
```

However this equals **false**, which I don't understand...

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6dvsza7/1/) to also show the behavior if you open up the web developer tools and look at the console.

Someone suggested, it had to do with precedence but reading about [precedence at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), I can't find a explanation to this.

Can anyone explain in a resonable simple way, what is going on there?

Comment: Do you expect `1 < 2 < 3` to actually work as in math, or do you understand that it does *not* actually work as in regular math notation…?

Comment: Just to clarify, why do you think it makes sense?

Comment: I don't actually know how it works in Maths, so no to your question there @deceze lol

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It seems like it would make sense as 1 is less than, 2 and 2 is less than 3, but starting to realise, that's not how it works...

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding the way how does it works. If you write `3 > 2 > 1`, the first operation is actually `3 > 2` which obviously returns `true`. But then it's `true > 1` which returns `false`, because `true` is being changed by the math operator to `1`.

In the `1 < 2 < 3` example, it returns true, because `1 < 2` returns `true` and `true < 3` operation returns `true` aswell, because `true` is again being changed into `1` and `1` is obviously smaller than `3`.

Answer (score 1):

An idea

1<2<3 = (1<2)<3 = (true)<3 = (1)<3 = true

3>2>1 = (3>2)>1 = (true)>1 = (1)>1 = false

Answer (score 1):

`1 < 2 < 3` in javascript corresponds to `((1 < 2) < 3)`, that corresponds to `true < 3`. You're actually comparing booleans with integers, it doesn't make any sense in my opinion.

If you want to make two comparisons at once you should rewrite the condition as `3 > 2 && 2 > 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(1 < 2 < 3);
```

evaluates as in the following way:

`console.log(true < 3);` is `console.log(1 < 3);` prints `true`

Then `console.log(3 > 2 > 1)`

evaluates as in the following way:

`console.log(true > 1)` is `console.log(1 > 1)` prints `false`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, chaining of comparison operators won't work; it will first evaluate the first comparison to true/false, convert it into 1/0 and then do the second comparsion:

```
1 < 2 < 3   =>   (1 < 2) < 3
            =>      true < 3
            =>         1 < 3
            =>          true    

3 > 2 > 1   =>   (3 > 2) > 1
            =>      true > 1
            =>         1 > 1
            =>         false
```

You should instead split it into two separate comparsions: `1 < 2 && 2 < 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the precedence of the operation from left to right, and the fach that 
true is equivalent to (1)

```
console.log(3 > 2 > 1);
3 > 2 => true;
console.log(true > 1 );
1 > 1 => false;
true > 1 => false;
```